# SQL-Underline with hash sign in column names

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we use underline with a # sign in column name in SQL?

Like Supplier(Sunp#, SName, Address,City, TelNo) is permissable in SQL or do the underline and # sign have a special meaning?(Assume Sunp to be underlined)

Comment: [Underline](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/u/underlin.htm) is a text formatting effect. Did you mean [underscore](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/u/undersco.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

You can, no special meaning.

```
SQL> create table supplier
  2    (sunp#          number,
  3     supplier_name  varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Read on [Database object names and qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129).

> Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@).

> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0).